# Web2py: Submit Javascript Vars with Form

Tags: javascript, web2py

I'm attempting to submit additional data to the server when I submit a form. Here is the form:

```
<form class="class" action="{{=URL('default','function')}}" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="first" name="first" class="span3"/>
                    <button id="button" type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
                </div>
</form>
```

I've tried to do submit the additional data a couple different ways:

```
    <script>
        $('#button').submit(function(){
            var cost = +($("#cost").text().replace('$','')); 
            $.getScript("{{=URL('default','function')}}"+"?cost="+cost);
        }); 
    </script>
```

and

```
    <script>
        $('#button').submit(function(){
            var cost = +($("#cost").text().replace('$','')); 
            $.post("{{=URL('default','function')}}",{cost:cost});
        }); 
    </script>
```

However, only the form data appears in request.vars. How can I submit the additional script variable "cost" with the rest of the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an id to your form or to a div in your form (calling it '#addinput' here), then append a hidden input once your button is clicked:

```
<script>
    $('#button').click(function(){
        var cost = +($("#cost").text().replace('$','')); 
        $('#addinput').append('<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'+cost+'" id="id">')
    }); 
</script>
```